# What's the point of only releasing a documentary in a very small number of theaters rather than streaming it on the Internet?

Tags: documentary

I'm interested in watching the upcoming documentary called [Nuclear Now](https://www.nuclearnowfilm.com/). Unfortunately, the producers have decided to only release it in a very small number of theaters. In NYC, it's shown for 1 day in 3 theaters and for 1 week in 1 more theater. Given such a limited release, it's clear that it's highly unlikely that the film makers will make much of a profit from in-person theaters. So... why not just make it available for streaming on Netflix or HBO Max or Hulu, etc? Or even just release it on Youtube if their goal is to maximize the number of people who will hear their message?

I can understand why this is the case with [blockbusters](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110771/why-was-tenet-released-to-cinemas-only-even-though-most-of-them-are-closed-thro) but it doesn't seem to make sense for documentaries.

Comment: There is an endless list of theatres onhttps://www.nuclearnowfilm.com/watch , not a "handful". The basic premise of this question is false.

Comment: @BCdotWEB *all of NYC* has just one theater streaming the movie for more than 1 day. Compare that to how many theaters screen the latest blockbuster in the city.

Comment: @BCdotWEB but sure, changed "handful" to "very small number.

Comment: No matter how many theaters there are, the number by itself seems to be more of a marketing issue than just some artistic choice. There are several strategies that could explain that.

Comment: @OldPadawan sure but I presume the goal of the movie maker is to either make make money or maximize the viewership numbers... neither of which seem to achieved here. For maximum exposure just dump the thing on Youtube for free. For maximum profits sign a deal with Netflix. Releasing it to a small number of theaters makes no sense.

Comment: if you want something people will talk about or fight for, make it rare. That's one technic :) If you want to minimize the risk of losing money, same : small number of theaters.

Comment: You could re-cast this in a more positive light & maybe draw less backlash. "What are the benefits of a limited theatrical release for an independent movie?"

Comment: Your comment about maximum exposure or maximum profits seems to assume those are the only two goals of a film; and also that signing a deal with Netflix (for example) is something a filmmaker could just choose to do. Perhaps Netflix has already told them "show us solid returns for a limited theatre release and we’ll talk, but right now we don’t feel like your film is a good fit for the Netflix brand."

Comment: @ToddWilcox why else would you bother releasing a movie, other than to make a profit or have as many people as possible see it?

Comment: You're confusing sheer numbers with *real* exposure. Dumping it on youtube is absolutely not the same as setting it up for film festivals with the potential to win awards. This is a film by Oliver Stone, it's not like he doesn't have previous. An unknown director would probably kill to be able to go straight to theatres with a documentary. Note they're also pushing the social media channels with teasers & influencers. Someone, somewhere, has thought this through.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all - as the guy obviously doesn't really *need* the money - if it didn't end up on YT or Vevo after it's done the rounds on the 'proper' channels.

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m still super confused as to what’s the point of making a documentary of this type if you’re not going to put it on YT or Netflix after for maximum exposure.

Comment: I was sure I'd just explained why you have the wrong idea of what constitutes 'maximum exposure'. Until you grasp that concept, the rest is going to continue to confuse you.

Comment: @Tetsujin are you basically saying that the goal is to get the 'elite' to watch it and the director couldn't care less if the other 99% ever sees it? That would actually be a fantastic answer!

Comment: ermmm . . .  no.

Comment: @Tetsujin then I have no idea whatsoever as to what you're trying to say

Comment: I'd gathered that, which is why I've given up trying.

Comment: @Tetsujin are you sure you understand the answer to my question as opposed to not knowing the answer and only pretending that you do? Because it sounds like the latter.

Comment: I'm sure - that's why I tried to point out initially that you are making some incorrect assumptions. That you appear to be approaching this entire question in an aggressive, 'no-one but me knows what I mean' manner, means I'm done now.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm finding it very difficult to find a way to explain that the goals of filmmaking can be very different from money or "maximum exposure". Some filmmakers may gain personal fulfillment and find purpose in life by making films. Those feelings of purpose and fulfillment may be reached by getting "maximum exposure", but then again maybe that is not fulfilling for all filmmakers. Some filmmakers may dream of having a limited theatrical release, either instead of or previous to an online digital release.

Comment: Also note that if your question is really a complaint about your not being able to see this movie as soon as you would like, then that is not appropriate here. If you're honestly curious about why a movie would have a limited, exclusive theatrical release, I feel like the existing answers and comments have a lot for you to think about to better understand.

Comment: The answer here is a great example of a person who is not only seeking money or exposure when deciding how to release a film: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110771/why-was-tenet-released-to-cinemas-only-even-though-most-of-them-are-closed-thro?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm going to see it and the timing actually works well for me. What I don't understand is why a movie with a political agenda would make it so hard for voters to actually see it.

Comment: Ah I didn’t understand your question was about politics. There isn’t an election for several months yet and the next major election is 18 months away. There’s plenty of time to consider politics after film desires are fulfilled

Comment: @ToddWilcox this is, without a doubt, a political documentary. The director wants to convince people that nuclear is safe and useful for the future of humanity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are release requirements for some awards, such as the Academy Awards and NY Film Critics Circle awards. This might be the biggest in-theatre release they could get and they went with it for award qualification and then it may move to streaming.

Another possible reason is that the distribution company may have agreements with theatre chains or other business reasons to release exclusively in theaters before going to a digital or physical release.

Finally, the producers may have an artistic or cultural preference for an exclusive theatrical release before any further releases.

Answer (score 4):

A limited release is usually a way to combine minimum financial risks with some maximum "*bush telegraph*" effect.

> [Limited theatrical release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_theatrical_release) is a film distribution strategy of releasing a new film in a few theaters across a country, typically art house theaters in major metropolitan markets. The purpose is often used to gauge the appeal of specialty films, like documentaries, independent films and art films.

Now, according to the [American Film Market](https://americanfilmmarket.com/how-many-independent-films-get-a-theatrical-release/):

> For many independent filmmakers, whether or not their film reaches the big screen means everything. No matter the money to be made via television deals or the massive audiences possible with VOD, a theatrical release is where it's at. Seeing a film played in a theater is still regarded as the best way to experience the art form. It's also, understandably, the goal of many film producers. By looking at a complete set of films made in a single year, we can see how likely it is that a given film will realize that dream, and it turns out that there's actually a pretty good chance a film will play to a paying audience at some point, if that's what the film-maker sets out to do.

> However, the numbers say that an independent film will, five times out of six, not go on to make much money in theaters. Knowing how to maximize revenue from the home market remains an essential skill for an independent producer.

There are also other reasons (even if they don't seem to apply in your case):

> A common practice by film studios is to give highly anticipated and critically acclaimed films a limited release on or before December 31 in Los Angeles County, California, to qualify for Academy Award nominations (as by its rules). Highly anticipated documentaries also receive limited releases at the same time in New York City, as the rules for the Academy Award for Best Documentary Feature mandate releases in both locations. The films are almost always released to a wider audience in January or February of the following year.

So, no matter how many theaters there are, the number by itself seems to be more of a marketing issue than just some artistic choice. If you want something people will talk about or fight for, make it rare. That's one technic. If you want to minimize the risk of losing money, do the same: a small number of theaters. Combine marketing technics when needed.

More to read: [Why Are Limited Release Movies Still A Distribution Method?](https://filmschoolrejects.com/limited-release-movies-still-distribution-method-2018/) -- [Film distribution](https://neilchasefilm.com/film-distribution/) -- [film distribution strategies (from legal POV)](https://rodriqueslaw.com/blog/film-distribution-strategies-use-when-financing-your-movie/)